# Undefined method `avatar' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, paperclip

I'm trying to print an image using the Paperclip gem.

When I print using views/devise/edit.html.rb everything looks good but when I want print in views/layout/application.html.rb I'm getting this error in console:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `avatar' for nil:NilClass):
     7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
     8: </head>
     9: <body>
    10: <%= image_tag @user.avatar.url(:thumb) %>
    11: <%= yield %>
    12: 
    13: </body>
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:10:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___4291648939640547438_70254980514000'
```

This is User.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => ["300x300>"], :thumb => ["100x100>"], :page => ["800"] }


end
```

This is application_controller.rb:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
 before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password, :avatar) }


  end


end
```

Comment: `@user.avatar` is the problem. `@user`, at that point, is `nil`. Figure out why.

Comment: Given your error is in the layout, you should use `current_user` instead of `@user`

Comment: How can I globally define current_users ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@user` here is undefined. You can define it in the controller or use Devise's `current_user` helper.

Replacing:

```
@user.avatar.url(:thumb)
```

with:

```
current_user.avatar.url(:thumb)
```

should get you past this error as long as a user is signed in when seeing this view. Otherwise you'll need to check for nil before calling #avatar.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you instantiate the @user object in your controller action. Are you doing:

```
def edit
  @user = current_user
end
```

Comment: Hi, When I add this. It just works on Index page. I whant to work on all pages
def index
   @user = current_user
  end

Comment: You have to instantiate an object to have it available in a view. Look at a proper auth system like devise which will make current_user available to all views when a user is logged in. Otherwise you will need to add it to every action or to the global scope in application_controller etc, which sounds like a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

When I add this code it works on this pages:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def index
  @user = current_user
  end

  def home
      @user = current_user
  end

  def profile
      @user = current_user
  end
end
```

But I Whant to add on all pages globally :)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to set it globally, try to implement your logic in Application Controller